# Issues with my POST route with Next.js 13

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma

I have a little problem with my code, I'm trying to make a route to post a maintenance to a vehicle with next js 13 and prisma

I put you my different codes below and the response that I have in my console

app/api/vehicle/[id]/maintenance/route.ts

```
import prisma from '@/app/libs/prismadb';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

import getCurrentUser from '@/app/actions/getCurrentUser';
import getVehicleById from '@/app/actions/getVehicleById';

interface IParams {
  vehicleId: string;
}

export async function POST(
  request: Request,
  { params }: { params: IParams },
  ) {
  try {
    const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();
    
    console.log(currentUser, 'CURRENT_USER');
    const body = await request.json();
    console.log(body, 'VEHICLE_MAINTENANCE_CREATION_BODY');
    const {
      maintenanceType,
      maintenancePartner,
      maintenanceCity,
      maintenanceDate,
      maintenanceMileage,
      maintenanceCost,
      maintenanceDescription,
    } = body;
    const { vehicleId } = params;
    console.log(vehicleId, 'VEHICLE_ID');

    if (!currentUser?.id || !currentUser?.email) {
      return new NextResponse('Unauthorized', { status: 401 });
    }
    const currentVehicle = await getVehicleById(vehicleId as string);
    console.log(currentVehicle, 'CURRENT_VEHICLE');
    

    if (!currentVehicle) {
        return new NextResponse('Not Found', { status: 404 });
    }

    const vehicleMaintenance = await prisma.vehicleMaintenance.create({
      data: {
        maintenanceType,
        maintenancePartner,
        maintenanceCity,
        maintenanceDate,
        maintenanceMileage,
        maintenanceCost,
        maintenanceDescription,
        vehicle: {
          connect: {
            id: currentVehicle.id,
            
          },
        },
      },
    });

    return NextResponse.json(vehicleMaintenance);
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    console.log(error, 'VEHICLE_MAINTENANCE_CREATION_ERROR');
    return new NextResponse('Internal Server Error', { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

app/actions/getVehicleById.ts

```
import prisma from '@/app/libs/prismadb';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import getCurrentUser from './getCurrentUser';

const getVehicleById = async (vehicleId: string) => {
  try {
    const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();

    if (!currentUser?.email) {
      return null;
    }

    const vehicle = await prisma.vehicle.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: vehicleId,
      },
    });

    return vehicle;
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log(error, 'VEHICLE_GET_ERROR');
    return new NextResponse('Internal Server Error', { status: 500 });
  }
};

export default getVehicleById;
```

prisma/schema.prisma

```
model Vehicle {
  id           String            @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  brand        String
  model        String
  year         Int
  fuelType     String
  transmission String
  vin          String            @unique
  licensePlate String            @unique
  createdAt    DateTime          @default(now())
  maintenance  Maintenance[]
  documents    VehicleDocument[]
  user         User              @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId       String            @map("userId") @db.ObjectId
}

model Maintenance {
  id                     String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  maintenanceType        String
  maintenancePartner     String
  maintenanceCity        String
  maintenanceDate        DateTime
  maintenanceMileage     Int
  maintenanceCost        Int
  maintenanceDescription String
  vehicle                Vehicle  @relation(fields: [vehicleId], references: [id])
  vehicleId              String   @map("vehicleId") @db.ObjectId
}

model VehicleDocument {
  id           String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  documentType String
  documentPath String
  vehicle      Vehicle @relation(fields: [vehicleId], references: [id])
  vehicleId    String  @map("vehicleId") @db.ObjectId
}
```

console response

```
{
  id: '646f35b0f889c7ad4569f983',
  lastName: 'test',
  firstName: 'test',
  email: 'test@mail.fr',
  phoneNumber: '0145984236',
  category: 'professionnel',
  company: 'test',
  image: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/dcsgrhtmj/image/upload/v1685470687/tiop9tc0gjm2s0cxiy8a.jpg',
  hashedPassword: '$2b$12$Z3YjwxKVaF8WWGpvw8ab/eNYfMrXcbpOWTxaC0mBdSUYLDpOydOPa',
  confirmPassword: null,
  verified: false,
  verifiedAt: null,
  createdAt: 2023-05-25T10:17:20.277Z,
  updatedAt: 2023-05-30T18:18:07.513Z
} CURRENT_USER
{
  maintenanceType: 'Test',
  maintenancePartner: 'test',
  maintenanceCity: 'test',
  maintenanceDate: '2023-04-05',
  maintenanceMileage: '8000',
  maintenanceCost: '11000',
  maintenanceDescription: 'test',
  vehicleId: '6478dec877d5e3adf501300f'
} VEHICLE_MAINTENANCE_CREATION_BODY
undefined VEHICLE_ID
PrismaClientValidationError: 
Invalid `prisma.vehicle.findUnique()` invocation:

{
  where: {
?   id?: String,
?   vin?: String,
?   licensePlate?: String
  }
}

Argument where of type VehicleWhereUniqueInput needs at least one argument. Available args are listed in green.

Note: Lines with ? are optional.

    at Ai.validate (D:\platform\PlatformApp\platform-cars-app\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:144:73)
    at un.createMessage (D:\platform\PlatformApp\platform-cars-app\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:161:1298)
    at D:\platform\PlatformApp\platform-cars-app\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:174:10818
    at Object.runInChildSpan (D:\platform\PlatformApp\platform-cars-app\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:171:1343)
    at t._executeRequest (D:\platform\PlatformApp\platform-cars-app\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:174:10795)
    at async getVehicleById (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./app/actions/getVehicleById.ts:17:25)
    at async POST (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./app/api/vehicle/[id]/maintenance/route.ts:27:32)
    at async eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:242:37) {
  clientVersion: '4.14.1'
} VEHICLE_GET_ERROR
NextResponse [Response] {
  [Symbol(realm)]: { settingsObject: {} },
  [Symbol(state)]: {
    aborted: false,
    rangeRequested: false,
    timingAllowPassed: false,
    requestIncludesCredentials: false,
    type: 'default',
    status: 500,
    timingInfo: null,
    cacheState: '',
    statusText: '',
    headersList: HeadersList {
      cookies: null,
      [Symbol(headers map)]: [Map],
      [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: [Array]
    },
    urlList: [],
    body: { stream: undefined, source: 'Internal Server Error', length: 21 }
  },
  [Symbol(headers)]: HeadersList {
    cookies: null,
    [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(1) { 'content-type' => [Object] },
    [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: [ [Array] ]
  },
  [Symbol(internal response)]: {
    cookies: ResponseCookies { _parsed: Map(0) {}, _headers: [HeadersList] },
    url: undefined
  }
} CURRENT_VEHICLE
Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')
    at POST (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./app/api/vehicle/[id]/maintenance/route.ts:34:120)
    at async eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:242:37)
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')
    at POST (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./app/api/vehicle/[id]/maintenance/route.ts:34:120)
    at async eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:242:37) VEHICLE_MAINTENANCE_CREATION_ERROR
```